# Can I do this in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to get the `**ID_RE**` with the highest columns in `**Date_Enter,Date_Process,Date_Shipment**`

For example, here have a three rows.

```
 - **1,2012-02-01,2016-02-01,2015-02-01,Send for MX4343**
 - **2,2013-02-01,2008-04-01,2009-02-01,It's For trade**
 - **3,2018-02-01,2019-05-01,2007-02-01,Like a environment**
```

This is the highest:

`3,2018-02-01,2019-05-01,2007-02-01,Like a environment`

I've been trying with this:

```
SELECT 
MAX(Date_Enter),
MAX(Date_Process),
MAX(Date_Shipment),
Description
FROM Reports
```

But, not works

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Reports](
    [ID_RE] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Date_Enter] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Date_Process] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Date_Shipment] [varchar](20),
    [Description] [varchar](20)
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Reports] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID_RE] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO
```

Here we have some information

```
insert into Reports(Date_Enter,Date_Process,Date_Shipment,Description) values('2012-02-01 02:25:23','2016-02-01 08:45:23','2015-02-01 05:35:23','Send for MX4343')

insert into Reports(Date_Enter,Date_Process,Date_Shipment,Description) values('2013-02-01 01:52:23','2008-04-01 12:45:23','209-02-01 07:35:43','It is For trade')

insert into Reports(Date_Enter,Date_Process,Date_Shipment,Description) values('2018-02-01 04:34:33','2019-05-01 04:35:44','2007-02-01 09:35:09','Like a environment')
```

Comment: Highest is decided on which date?? You have three dates

Comment: As per your result it look you have to just `select top 1 * from tableName order by ID_RE Desc`. Replace order by column with as per your requirement

Comment: try this?:
SELECT 
ID_RE
FROM Reports
where Date_Enter=(select MAX(Date_Enter) FROM Reports)

Comment: *On a side note* - As reflected by the question tag, people are still using SQL Server 2005 which really amazes me. Even the extended support for SQL Server 2005 ended in Apr '16 as mentioned [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/sql-server/sql-server-2005). Please consider using some newer versions of this software to stay up-to-date.

Comment: @PSK for the three columns Date_Enter,Date_Process,Date_Shipment

Comment: @BData Hi, I want to get the highest in the three columns, compared to all ID_RE

Comment: Then order by all three columns. Please try some of the answers

Comment: @RocioJ I have updated the answer for all the 3 columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `order by` as per your requirement as below. If you wants that your data fetch the record which `Date_Enter` is max then apply order by on that column. If you wants to get record by `multiple order condition` then you can also apply order on multiple columns.

**Order by Only Date_Enter:**

```
SELECT TOP 1
    ID_RE
    Date_Enter,
    Date_Process,
    Date_Shipment,
    Description
FROM Reports
ORDER BY Date_Enter DESC
```

**Order by with Date_Enter,Date_Process and Date_Shipment:**

```
SELECT TOP 1
    ID_RE
    Date_Enter,
    Date_Process,
    Date_Shipment,
    Description
FROM Reports
ORDER BY Date_Enter DESC, Date_Process DESC, Date_Shipment DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

Query you have written is not correct. I suggest you to read `GROUP BY` in SQL

**Note:** You have following two issues in your question data.

1- Date_Shipment is not correct date as 209 is not a valid year
2-  Data type of [Date_Shipment] is `VARCHAR` it should be `DATETIME`,

```
insert into Reports(Date_Enter,Date_Process,Date_Shipment,Description) values('2013-02-01 01:52:23','2008-04-01 12:45:23','209-02-01 07:35:43','It is For trade')
```

**Solution :**

If you want to find the `MAX` based on all  3 columns and decide based on that, you can write like following query.

```
SELECT 
 ID_RE,
   (SELECT MAX(MaxDate)
      FROM (VALUES (Date_Enter),(Date_Process),(Date_Shipment)) AS FindMax(MaxDate)) 
   AS MaxDate

  FROM [dbo].[Reports]
```

if you want to find `MAX` based on 1 date column, you can try like following. Following query will return multiple records if `Date_Enter`  is same for 2 or more records.

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Reports]
WHERE Date_Enter =
(
 SELECT MAX(Date_Enter) FROM [dbo].[Reports]
)
```

If you simply want to get 1 records based on Date_Enter  you can try like following.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [dbo].[Reports]
ORDER BY Date_Enter DESC
```